# how to get two different shadow color horizontally in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a `box-shadow` with two different colours horizontally of a line. Is there any way to do it instead of `box-shadow`? I am trying to build the inner design of the screen.

```css
.neon-rod
{
  position: relative;
  height: 0.2vmin;
  width: 25vmin;
  background: red;
  left: 50vmin;
  box-shadow: 
  0.2vmin 0 0 0.1vmin #69e;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="neon-rod"></div>
```

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55G8f.png)

Above is the reference image of the design.

Codepen:- https://codepen.io/himanshu-pal/pen/vYejNZW

Comment: You can do this using :before, :after:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: I tried but it seems like both box-shadow and drop-shadow are not working with :before and :after psudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have increased the `blur` and `spread` of `box-shadow` property

```css
.neon-rod
{
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  left: 50vmin;
  box-shadow: 
  0 0 8px 4px #69e;
}
```

```html
<div class="neon-rod"></div>
```

With `:before`

```css
.neon-rod {
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #69e;
  left: 50vmin;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px #69e;
}

.neon-rod:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  background: #0f0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  bottom:3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="neon-rod"></div>
```

More details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: Hi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one box-shadow and use different colors for each. Just separate the shadows with a comma.

```css
.neon-rod
{
  position: relative;
  height: 1vmin;
  width: 25vmin;
  background: red;
  left: 50vmin;
  top: 10vmin;
  box-shadow: 
    0.2vmin 0.3vmin  1.6vmin #69e8,
    0.3vmin 0.4vmin 3.2vmin #69ea,
    0.3vmin 0.4vmin 4.8vmin #69ec,
    0.3vmin 0.4vmin 6.4vmin #69ef,
    -0.2vmin -0.3vmin 0.8vmin green;
}
```

```html
<div class="neon-rod"></div>
```

Comment: That much I know but Can I get the same fade effect as in the image. I tried but the thing is if I use spread in shadows it overflow vertically also. So in the end I get a concentrated highly contrasted shadow which is not working.